Direct integral decomposition in general situation
Recently I've seen very interesting article "Abelian von Neumann algebras, measure algebras and $L^\infty$-spaces" by Blecher, Goldstein, Labuschage, which discusses general abelian von Neumann algebras (without separability / $\sigma$-finiteness assumption). It made me wonder, whether there is a direct integral decomposition for general von Neumann algebras. Let me be more precise:
Whenever $M$ is a von Neumann algebra acting on a separable Hilbert space $H$ we have a decomposition result: there is a measure space $(X,\mu)$, measurable field of Hilbert spaces $(H_x)_x$ and von Neumann algebras $(M_x)_x$ such that each $M_x$ is a factor and $H\simeq \int_X^{\oplus}H_x d\mu(x)$, $M\simeq \int_X^{\oplus} M_x d\mu(x)$, $\mathcal{Z}(M)$ is isomorphic with diagonalisable operators, etc. (in fact we can get more information about $X,\mu$) - this is written e.g. in Dixmier's book "Von Neumann algebras".
To what extent similar result holds without separability assumption?

This is technically open, but most experts, I believe, think there’s no such thing. For example, take a II$_1$ factor $M$ and a free ultrafilter $\omega$ on $\mathbb{N}$. There’s likely no “nice” theory of direct integral decomposition that can deal with $(L^\infty(0, 1) \otimes M)^\omega$.

Most of whatever is known on the subject can be found in Chapter IV of Takesaki’s Theory of Operator Algebras I. He likes to write things as general as possible, including without assuming separability if feasible.
